# Change Java object type?

Tags: java

During the runtime of my programme, I would like to identify the type of an Object I would need to instantiate.

As an example: If a user is travelling from A to B, he can choose a transport method: car or push bike, Both will enable the user to travel, but the actual work processes are different. In a car you need to shift gears to move, on a bike you need to paddle. They would have a common set of methods, ie: "move", but their implementation would be different.

The rest of the programme doesn't need to know how 'move' is implemented...

Imagine:

```
public class Transport {
   public Object transportMethod;

   public Transport(tMet) {
      if (tMet.equals("car")) {
         transportMethod = new Car();
      }
      else if (tMet.equals("bike")) {
         transportMethod = new Bike();
      }
   }

   public Object returnTransportMethod() {
      return transportMethod();
   }
}
```

How can I now use the Bike or Car methods when I pass transportMethod back to another Class?

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: `instanceof` or compare `Class` types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That sounds like a bad idea to me. We have common operations - this is crying out for polymorphism.

Comment: @Jon I agree with you, I'm just lazy to write out a detailed answer. That's why we have you :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: But using `instanceof` is going in the wrong direction. Better not to suggest anything at all than to suggest an inappropriate solution, IMO.

Comment: @Jon As a factory, you could use the deciding factor to be a `String` as in your solution, or a `Class` or really anything that makes sense to compare with.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, but then `instanceof` still isn't useful IMO. Given the lack of context, I interpreted your `instanceof` suggestion to be something like: `if (transport instanceof Car) { ((Car) transport).move(); }`

Comment: @Jon OP didn't provide a type for the `tMet` variable, so I didn't want to make assumptions. I didn't mean `instanceof` in that sense, but I only read `I would like to identify the type of an Object` instead of the whole `I would like to identify the type of an Object I would need to instantiate.`

Answer (score 9):

> They would have a common set of methods, ie: "move", but their implementation would be different.

That sounds like they should both implement the same interface or extend the same abstract superclass then. Use that interface or superclass instead of `Object` in your `Transport` class. Actually, it sounds like your `Transport` class is more of a factory than transport in itself. But leaving that aside:

```
public interface Vehicle {
    void move();
}

public class Bike implements Vehicle {
    public void move() {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class Car implements Vehicle {
    public void move() {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class VehicleFactory {
   public Vehicle vehicle;

   public VehicleFactory(String method) {
      if (method.equals("car")) {
         vehicle = new Car();
      } else if (method.equals("bike")) {
         vehicle = new Bike();
      }
      // TODO: Decide what you want to do otherwise...
   }

   public Vehicle getVehicle() {
      return vehicle;
   }
}
```